# r markdown (knitr::kable): not print repeated values

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, kable

When using `knitr::kable(tibble)` is there a way not to show values if they are repetitions?

For example:

```
var1  var2  var3 
----------------
A     C     1
A     D     2
A     E     3
A     E     4
B     C     1
B     D     2
B     E     3
```

Should be printed as:

```
var1  var2  var3 
----------------
A     C     1
      D     2
      E     3
            4
      C     1
B     D     2
      E     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` and `duplicated` to remove the repeated value within each `var1`.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  mutate(var2 = replace(var2, duplicated(var2), '')) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(var1 = replace(var1, duplicated(var1), ''))

knitr::kable(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

kableExtra can group repeated rows together [documentation of the Latex/pdf version](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, message=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
iris3 <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice(1:3)
iris3 %>%
    knitr::kable(format = "latex") %>%
    kableExtra::collapse_rows(columns = 5, latex_hline = "major", valign = "top")
```
````

[image]

Somehow the html version of "[group rows via multi-row cell](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Group_rows_via_multi-row_cell)" doesn't work for the current version of kableExtra on Cran, it should work with the github version according to [this issue](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/624).

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R`

```
df1[1:2][(cbind(duplicated(df1[1]), duplicated(df1[1:2])))] <- ''
knitr::kable(df1)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), var2 = c("C", 
"D", "E", "E", "C", "D", "E"), var3 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```